# Apache 2.4 with SSL config - Have 403 Forbidden

Tags: ssl, http-status-code-403, apache2.4

I have an issue with my apache config.
I just set a new windows server with Apache2.4 and SSL certificate but when i want to access to my https://localhost, i have a 403 Forbidden error.

This is my vhost-myproject.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "D:/www/myproject/public"
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
  SetEnv ZF2_PATH D:/zend/ZendFramework-2.4.13/library
  ServerName myproject.fr
  <Directory "D:/www/myproject/public">
      Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "D:/mycertificate.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/mykey.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]


</IfModule>
```

And my hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost myprojet.fr
ip_server       myprojet.fr localhost
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does the error.log say exactly?

Comment: Nothing special in error.log

Comment: I don't know if it's related, i think it is but i have 403 forbidden only php file. When i try to access html file, it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `httpd.conf` file, and make sure that parameters "Listen" and "ServerName" are configured like "Listen 80" and "ServerName localhost:80".